# css3 transform 3d background picture on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, translate3d

Hello I'm looking for the effect on the header picture as seen here:
http://www.gamebreaker.tv/news-main/david-lynch-leaving-twin-peaks-revival/

Any tips on how to make it? or is there a ready to go solution for this?

Comment: This effect is called "parallax scrolling". Google will show you plenty results with examples.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is parallax effect. I think http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ this url should help.